# Javascript Not Well Loaded in Android Web Browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

My website is a custom eCommerce website. Some JS I use JQuery Library integration.

The problem I faced now is, whenever I open the website using Android Web Browser (Samsung A7 2016 android 7.0), all my custom JS (without JQuery integration) are not work. I thought it was my phone problem, but I received plenty complain from my customer said the same thing.

I ran the web on iPhone, Android 6, Android 7.1 is all good, except on Android 7.0 (Samsung A7).

Here's how it look on Samsung A7 Android 7.0, at the bottom right cart icon, the counter is not showing up and its not adding up when I added item.:
[image]

And here how it lloks in Samsung Tab A Android 7.1.1
[image]

Is Android Platform problem or my JS error?

ps: It works very well on desktop :)

Here's some sample JS code.

```
function cartItemCounter(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("cartItemCounter").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("cartItemCounter2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "URL_HERE?type=itemCounter", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Please post some code instead of screenshots of the site, this is almost spam.

Comment: I added a JS sample. I don't think it's a JS error because the console didn't prompted me an error. Instead, it cannot run on certain android web browser, but some of android (which is not android 7.0) works well.